# How to sort List<Map<String,String>> by key1 descending order and key2 ascending order if key1 has same values

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a List

```
List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("productNumber", "107-001");
            map1.put("productNumber", "108-001");
            map2.put("productNumber", "109-001");
            map.put("price", "1.99");
            map1.put("price", "1.02");
            map2.put("price", "1.99");
            list.add(map);
            list.add(map1);
            list.add(map2);
```

I sort it by price and revers result

```
formattedResult = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(m -> Double.parseDouble(m.get("price")))).collect(Collectors.toList());
            Collections.reverse(formattedResult);
```

The result of this :

```
**price  productNumber**
1.99   109-001
1.99   107-001
1.02   108-001
```

I want to sort it like

```
**price  productNumber**
    1.99   107-001
    1.99   109-001
    1.02   108-001
```

If prices equal - compare by product number, end first should be productNumber with a lower value.
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier if you build your `Comparator` in two steps. So try this and print them out.  It works like this.

- first it sorts the price in reversed order.
- Then t sorts the product number in regular order for equal prices.

```
    Comparator<Map<String, String>> comp = Comparator
        .comparing(m ->Double.parseDouble(m.get("price"))
                         ,Comparator.reverseOrder());
    comp = comp.thenComparing(m -> m.get("productNumber"));
```

Apply it like so.

```
        List<Map<String, String>> formattedResult =
                list.stream().sorted(comp)  
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());


        formattedResult.forEach(m -> System.out.println(
                m.get("price") + " : " + m.get("productNumber")));
```

This prints

```
1.99 : 107-001
1.99 : 109-001
1.02 : 108-001
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to reverse result if you use the right comparator (and you can chain comparators, too):

```
    final Comparator<Map<String, String>> byPrice = Comparator.comparing(m -> Double.parseDouble(m.get("price")), Comparator.reverseOrder());

    formattedResult = list.stream().sorted(byPrice.thenComparing(m -> m.get("productNumber"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create reverse comparator for `productNumber`

```
 Comparator<Map<String, String>> productNumberReversed =  Comparator.comparing((Map<String, String> mp) -> mp.get("productNumber")).reversed();
```

And then add it sort method comparator using [thenComparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-)

```
formattedResult = list.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map<String, String> m) -> Double.parseDouble(m.get("price"))).thenComparing(productNumberReversed)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.reverse(formattedResult);
```